# Reading a date from keyboard until it's correct - in scala

Tags: scala, date, iterator

I would like to continuously prompt the user to enter a date in a given format, until he/she gets it right.

This is what I've done:

```
def readDate(prompt: String): Date = {
    var date: Option[Date] = None
    Iterator.continually {
      val startDateString = readLine(prompt)
      val startDate = catching(classOf[ParseException]).opt(asDate(startDateString))
      date = startDate
      startDate
    }.takeWhile(_ == None).foreach {
      date =>
        println("Incorrect format. Try again.")
    }
    date.get
  }
```

where `asDate` just uses `SimpleDateFormat.parse` on the entered String.

Now, this seems to work, but I'm pretty sure it's not the right way.

I don't really understand how to handle these chained iterators (since both Iterator.continually and takeWhile return an instance of AbstractIterator).

I have basically two questions:

1) Is there a way to "return" `startDate` from `Iterator.continually`? I've tried and failed `map`-ping it. I want this in order to get rid of the `var date` and `date = startDate`.

2) If I didn't want anything to happen between the reads, what would I do with the last foreach? I've seen that nothing works if I just remove it (I think because of next() not being invoked),  but is it OK to leave it there like this:

`takeWhile(_ == None).foreach { date => {}}` ?

Is there a better way than the "empty" foreach?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `find` instead of `takeWhile`--this will keep dropping entries until a good one comes through.  Then you have an `Option`, so you just need

```
def readDate(prompt: String): Date = {
  Iterator.continually {
    catching(classOf[ParseException]).opt(asDate( readLine(prompt) ))
  }.find(_.isDefined).get
}
```

if you don't want to print anything.  If you do want to print something, you can put it into the loop.

```
def readDate(prompt: String): Date = {
  Iterator.continually {
    catching(classOf[ParseException]).opt(asDate( readLine(prompt) )) match {
      case None =>
        println("Incorrect format.  Try again.")
        None
      case x => x
    }
  }.find(_.isDefined).get
}
```

I'm not sure that this is dramatically clearer, but it's definitely shorter and does those things you wanted.

I'd probably use a tail-recursive function instead:

```
import annotation.tailrec
@tailrec def readDate(prompt: String, again: Boolean = false): Date = {
  if (again) println("Incorrect format.  Try again.")
  catching(classOf[ParseException]).opt(asDate( readLine(prompt) )) match {
    case Some(date) => date
    case None => readDate(prompt, true)
  }
}
```

The logic seems a bit clearer to me here.

Comment: Wonderful! I also think the tail-recursive function is clearer. I went ahead and implemented a more generic version of readDate, like this: def readUntilRight[T](prompt: String)(op:String => T): T = {..} So I can do: readUntilRight("")(asDate) or readUntilRight("int pls")(_.toInt)   Thanks!

Comment: @teo - If you're using Scala 2.10, you probably want the more generic version to use `Try` (since who knows what `op` will throw): `Try(op(readLine(prompt))) match { case Success(date) => date; case Failure(_) => readUntilRight(prompt)(op) }`

Answer (score 2):

I would write it as

```
def readDate(prompt: String): Date = 
  try asDate(readLine(prompt))
  catch { case e: ParseException => 
    println("Incorrect format. Try again.")
    readDate(prompt)
  }
```